# Why do we use an article before some words like

Tags: british-english

I have a problem with the use of article
There is a rule that we can't use an article before an uncountable noun but in many words we do, the words are a headache, a cold, a hurry
Can anybody tell me what the reason behind it?

Comment: I've had many headaches in my life.  It's countable.  Likewise, I've had many colds.  But I never hurry (just ask my wife).

Comment: Why do you think *headache* is a non-count noun? "I had two headaches last week" is a valid sentence, for example.

Comment: Thank you sir but you had better explain fully

Comment: Sir can you give me any example of a hurry

Comment: "A hurry" is kind of an exception (though not entirely).  The idiom is not readily derived from the verb "hurry" but has evolved over, probably, several centuries.  One can view it as meaning "an  instance of hurrying".  More obvious in a sentence like "In my hurry to leave I knocked over a pile of books".  One could easily follow this by "But in my hurry the next day I only knocked over some dishes", so there can be more than one "hurry".